# Vertical Layout - calculate and apply DIV height

Tags: javascript

I have put together a simple vertical layout.  It consists of a title bar and content.  The title bar can have a varying height, so I use `.height()` to determine it, and then `$(window).height()` to find my remaining space.

The remaining space (less some padding) should fill the rest of the 'view'.  However I am `3px` away - can anyone explain why?

*edit:* I am compensating for the `3px` with the `(4 * padding) - 3)` line of code.

*JSFiddle showing the issue [here](http://jsfiddle.net/drXWD/49/)*

```
function setScrollingDivHeight() {
 var div = $("#styleDivTitle");
 var padding = 5;
 $("#styleDivScrolling").height($(window).height()
  - $("#styleDivTitle").height() - (4 * padding) - 3);
}


$(window).load(function () {
 setScrollingDivHeight();
 $(window).resize(setScrollingDivHeight);
});
```

Comment: This bit perhaps: `(4 * padding) - 3)`? Other than that, what exactly do you mean by "I'm 3px away" - your JSFiddle looks perfectly aligned

Comment: Yes sorry, didn't describe that very well.  I was expecting `4 * padding` to be all that is required - however I've subtracted the `3px`to line things up manually.  Edited OP to this effect.

Comment: I think this is linked to `padding:.25em 5px .25em 5px;` on `#styleDivTitle`.  Changing the calculation to use `..$("#styleDivTitle").outerHeight(true) - (2*padding)` also aligns correctly.

Comment: `#styleDivScrolling` uses `padding:5px 0px 5px 0px;`, which is where `(2 * padding)` comes from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I used here was as follows, the key difference being using `.outHeight(true)`:

```
var padding = 5;

function setScrollingDivHeight() {
    $("#styleDivScrolling").height($(window).height() - $("#styleDivTitle").outerHeight(true) - (2*padding));
}

$(window).load(function () {
    setScrollingDivHeight();
    $(window).resize(setScrollingDivHeight);
});
```

JSFiddle of the result [here](http://jsfiddle.net/drXWD/59/).